# R: iterate through list of regression models for ggplot

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, regression

I have six regression models stored in different variables. I tried putting them in a list using:

```
modellist <- c(model1, model2....)
```

I want to use the following loop:

```
for (x in 1:6) {

  p1 <- ggplot(modellist[[x]], aes(.fitted, .resid))+geom_point()

  p1 <- p1+stat_smooth(method="loess")+
        geom_hline(yintercept=0, col="red", linetype="dashed")

  plotlist <- c(plotlist, p1)
}
```

... to create a list of plots I can display with `marrangeGrob`.

But `ggplot` doesn't accept `modellist[[x]]` as input and instead gives the error:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

How can I store the models to iterate through them?

Comment: It looks like you concatenated them into a vector with `c()` instead of putting them in a list. Try using `list()`.

Comment: wow, thats it. thanks!

Comment: Given that loops are often frowned upon in the `R` world, another approach would be to define the function you want to apply to each list item and then use something like `lapply(modellist, the_function_you_defined)`.

Comment: If you stick with the `for` loop, you might want to change it to `for (x in 1:length(modellist))` in case your model count changes.

Comment: @AdamSmith Normally I'll [reject and edit any suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20088753) that leaves or improves "thanks" lines, but seeing that you put more effort into the edit than the standard author I've approved it. Please, PLEASE, always remove these sorts of lines whenever you can. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/213671).

Comment: @gunr2171 - The elaboration is appreciated. In general I will not touch a "thanks" line (adding the period was unconscious). While I'm sympathetic to the "remove them" camp, personally I won't cut out that bit of humanity and etiquette someone wanted to convey, particularly when it's presumably sincere. I'm a hard enough editor elsewhere.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Question: are you referring to normal professional courtesy?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, a `lapply` example:

```
library(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
model1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)
model2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
modellist <- list(model1, model2)

ggplot_linear_model <- function(lm.input) {
  x <- ggplot(lm.input, aes(.fitted, .resid))+
       geom_point()+
       stat_smooth(method="loess")+
       geom_hline(yintercept=0, col="red", linetype="dashed")
  return(x)
}

lapply(modellist, ggplot_linear_model)
```